# Running JUnit5 Test in Parallel But Want To Leave Some Tests Sequential

Tags: java, junit5

I have a project that we have many Junit tests. We just did a large migration from JUnit4 to JUnit5. We would like to run most of the tests in parallel but have a couple that need to be ran sequentially. Is there any way to use JUnit5 and run tests both ways?

The reason I ask is that I have 4 tests that load a database into memory and I am loading data into this database. Then I run tests on that database. These are the four tests I need to run sequentially and cannot run in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely want to use `@ResourceLock` annotation on tests
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/snapshot/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution-synchronization

Comment: From the example in the document it looks like the tests need to be in same test class. These four tests are each in their own tests class and extending a super class.

Comment: No, its global across all tests. You can put that annotation also on class and it behaves as if you would have put that on each method on that class. You may want to try it on super class too.

Answer (score 5):

You might take a look at `@Isolated` annotation
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.7.1/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/parallel/Isolated.html.

It guarantees that test-class won't run in parallel with other classes.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Parallel Test Execution and Single Thread Execution](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html):

> Since of maven-surefire-plugin:2.18, you can apply the JCIP annotation
>   @net.jcip.annotations.NotThreadSafe on the Java class of JUnit test
>   (pure test class, Suite, Parameterized, etc.) in order to execute it
>   in single Thread instance. The Thread has name
>   maven-surefire-plugin@NotThreadSafe and it is executed at the end of
>   the test run.

So you could annotate your test classes with `@NotThreadSafe` in order to get them executed on 1 same thread (named *maven-surefire-plugin@NotThreadSafe*).

```xml
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.stephenc.jcip</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcip-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```